# Visual Basic - Checking if a port is open

Tags: vb.net, network-programming

Ok, I'm making a Visual Basic GUI application to display whether a number of my ports are open for people to know whether things like my website and my Minecraft server are open.

My problem is I have absolutely no idea how to do this in Visual Basic.

Basically, I'm asking for something which sends a signal to an IP with a specific port, if it is open then return true, if it's closed, return false. Similar to: http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: What version of Visual Basic? VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "port scanner written in c# with asp.net" at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebSitePortScanner.aspx. It is C#, but it is simple enough to convert to VB.NET.

If you need VB, it will be harder, but searching on "port scanner" and "visual basic" should turn up something.